# set js-indent-level from .eslintrc?

Tags: flycheck, javascript, js2-mode

when I edit javascript, I'm usually actually editing someone else's code. Is there a way to dynamically set the value of `js-indent-level` from a `.eslintrc` file?

Comment: Considering that `.eslintrc` doesn't have to be a JSON, getting that information out will be hacky. An easy solution could be to bind running `--fix` to a key, or you could look into something like [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about `eslint` or it's rc file, but TMTOWTDI as the Perl folks are fond of saying. Here's is how I solved a similar problem for myself using `shell-command-to-string`. I needed to get the version of CMake that was installed on whatever system I happened to be on.

```el
(defvar cmake-mode-cmake-version
  (let (l)
    (setq l (shell-command-to-string
             (concat cmake-mode-cmake-executable " --version")))
    (string-match  (rx bow
                       (one-or-more digit)
                       "."
                       (one-or-more digit)
                       (zero-or-more "." (one-or-more digit))
                       eow)
                   l)
    (match-string 0 l))
 "The version of CMake from `cmake-mode-cmake-executable'")
```

First, we define a new variable `cmake-mode-cmake-version`. Then we run `shell-command-to-string` with a string that I concat together. At this point you're going to want to use something like `"grep indent-level .eslint"`. (Again, don't know anything about eslint. Just working off the cuff here). Next, in `string-match` we look for a version string using a regex constructed with the `rx` package. With `match-string` we return the result of the last match (the one we just did with `string-match`), and `cmake-mode-cmake-version` now contains something like '3.11.1'. It's not the most lispy code, but hopefully it's clear.

Now, you could of course forego the `concat`s, and the `string-match`s, etc. Assuming your rc file is list of "things = values" then we could imagine something like:

```el
(eval-after-load "js-mode"
  (defvar my/eslint-indent
    '(let (l)
      (setq l (shell-command-to-string "grep indent-level .eslintrc | egrep -o '\\d+$' | tr -d '\\n'"))
      l)
   "The indent level from .eslintrc"))
  (setq js-indent-level my/eslint-indent))
```

where we set `js-indent-level` after loading our chosen JavaScript mode. Of course this is just an example, and you'll have to tweak it some for your own needs.